# MacBook Pro 16 inch thermal throttling even when temperatures are low

Tags: cpu, macbook-pro, cooling

MBP : [image]

Laptop works fine with with high intensity tasks as below.

[image]

But sometimes I notice that when I start to use MacBook its cpu speed limit stays at 20% despite the low temperature. I use the app "HOT" to monitor it.
Below is where CPU limit is 100 as it's supposed to. But sometimes even when temperature is 50 Celsius  cpu speed limit stays at 20%. Only after a reboot it gets to 100%. Or it takes a very very long time.It might be inactivity of half a day or a day. But cannot predict when it will be reset. Is there any reason for this? Or is is it a hardware fault.
I have tried clean install of OS. NVRAM SCM ..etc all the resets. But issue stays the same.

[image]

Issue:
[image]

Comment: Plug the charger in the other side. Test again.

Comment: Will try the when this issue occurs next time. But do you know why ?

Comment: My google-fu is failing me right now, but someone on Ask Different did a study of power/heat/port variations & came to the conclusion [supported by many] that one side charges cooler than the other & affects throttling.

Comment: It didn't help as I have updated in the question even sometimes in low temperatures speed goes to 20% and does not return to normal